# how to extract specified text from payslip images using pytesseract

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract

I am newbie to  tesseract OCR, I have a bunch of images of  payslips, I want to automate the  date extraction from the  payslips, please help me how to do,

First, I am   trying to  extract the data from one payslip, it showing error:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
img = cv2.imread(r'E:/Receipts/Receipts/0a0ebd53.jpeg')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
TESSDATA_PREFIX='C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata'
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
# OR explicit beforehand converting
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(img)))
```

error:

```
200         }
    201 
--> 202         run_tesseract(**kwargs)
    203         filename = kwargs['output_filename_base'] + os.extsep + extension
    204         with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice)
    176 
    177     if status_code:
--> 178         raise TesseractError(status_code, get_errors(error_string))
    179 
    180     return True

TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language \'eng\' Tesseract couldn\'t load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')
```

please help me how to fix this error and also, please give a deep learning model suggestion.

Comment: do u have the environment variable TESSDATA_PREFIX ? its clearly mentioned in the error message

Comment: yes, Venkata Krishnan, I try to that one also, I add to the environment variable to my code, but it again showing the same error.

Comment: do you have the language downloaded ? in the specified path ?

Comment: no  venkata krishna

Comment: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/eng.traineddata download this file, put it in the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

Please read Image with PIL library and then passed image object to image_to_string(img_obj) as given below.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:/Program Files/TesseractOCR/tesseract.exe"
image_obj = Image.open(image_path)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image_obj))
```